# How do I modify the "Price Tier Schedule" after it's been set in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

How do I modify the "Price Tier Schedule" after it's been set in iTunes Connect?

I did not submit for request yet.

Here below is the screen shot and I want to make changes to the already-set-up Price Tier Schedule.
[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I finally figure out that by adding new schedules, you can purge the old ones. It's really a tricky design of Apple.